# bytesAvailable, readUTF() and ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sockets

I have a multiplayer game, which reads XML data from the server:

```
 _socket = new Socket();
 _socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, handleTcpData);
.....
private function handleTcpData(event:Event):void {
  while (_socket.bytesAvailable) {
     var str:String = _socket.readUTF();
     updateGUI(str);
  }
}
```

In most cases it works ok, but sometimes users complain that
the game hangs for them. They are able to send in commands to
the server, but from their descriptions I suspect, that the function
above doesn't work well for them and the `updateGUI()` stops being called.

This issue is difficult to debug... I think my server (in Perl/C,
non-forking, uses poll()) works well, I must be doing something
wrong at the Flash side.

Is it a good idea to call `readUTF()` here? It could well be that
only part of the UTF string arrives and then the Flash movie
would freeze in `readUTF()`, wouldn't it? (I've never seen that though)

**UPDATE:**

Yes thanks, I need to catch `EOFError`, also I've got a good advise 
in a mailing list that I must read `_socket.bytesAvailable` bytes
into a `ByteArray` and work with that (check if my complete message
arrived) - anything else is unreliable.

So I've come up with this, but still have a flaw there:

```
private function handleTcpData(event:Event):void {
       var len:uint;

       if (0 == _socket.bytesAvailable)
               return;

       try {
               _socket.readBytes(_ba, _ba.bytesAvailable, _socket.bytesAvailable);

               // read the length of the UTF string to follow
               while (_ba.bytesAvailable >= 2) {
                       len = _ba.readUnsignedShort();

                       // invalid length - reset
                       if (0 == len) {
                               trace('XXX invalid len = ' + len);
                               _ba.position = 0;
                               _ba.length = 0;
                               return;
                       }

                       if (_ba.bytesAvailable >= len) {
                               var str:String = _ba.readUTFBytes(len);
                               updateGUI(str);

                               // copy the remaining bytes
                               // (does it work? can it be improved?)
                               var newBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                               newBA.readBytes(_ba);
                               _ba = newBA;
                       }
               }
       } catch(e:Error) {
               trace('XXX ' + e);
               _ba.position = 0;
               _ba.length = 0;
               return;
       }
}
```

- when there are too many bytes available, for example 800
  and my messages are only 400 bytes long, then it stucks.

Also I wonder, if copying remaining bytes could be
improved (i.e. without allocating a new ByteArray each time)?

I can reproduce this flaw often, luckily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, I've found the solution. 
Due to TCP-nature there can be 2 problematic cases:

1) several UTF-strings with prefixes arrive at once
2) an incomplete UTF-string with prefix arrives

This code should handle both:

```
private function handleTcpData(event:Event):void {
// CASE 1, JUST KEEP EXTRACTING UTF-STRINGS
 while(_socket.bytesAvailable) {
 try{
   var str:String = _socket.readUTF();
   updateGUI(str);
  }catch(e:Error){
    // CASE 2 INCOMPLETE STRING,
    // WILL BE READ BY LATER handleTcpData CALL
    return;
  }
 }
}
```

Also, in my original code I was copying the ByteArray wrong way. I should have:

```
var newBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
_ba.readBytes(newBA);
_ba = newBA;
```

or even do it in-place without creating newBA.

Answer (score 1):

All `socket.read*` methods may throw `EOFError` and `IOError`, so make sure you are catching them. It may be something as simple as that?

Another thought, the `readUTF()` call assumes that the first two bytes (a short) should contain the length in bytes of the UTF-string. If your perl server doesn't send that length, it may be that the `readUTF()` call interprets the first UTF *character* as the byte length, and thus ends up waiting for more data which never arrives.

Try using:

```
  var str:String = _socket.readUTFBytes(_socket.bytesAvailable);
```

Other than that, you really need to be able to reproduce the issue or it's quite impossible to know if you have fixed it.

Comment: Yes thanks, my Perl-server sends that prefix length, this isn't a problem.